# selenium-rc in bsd

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, bsd

I'm trying to run selenium-rc in bsd and get the following error

```
12:45:40.740 WARN - POST /selenium-server/driver/ HTTP/1.1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Firefox couldn't be found in the path!
Please add the directory containing 'firefox-bin' to your PATH environment
variable, or explicitly specify a path to Firefox like this:
*firefox /blah/blah/firefox-bin
```

Adding firefox-bin to my path does not help. 
What is the second option? ("or explicitly specify a path to Firefox like this")

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying specifying the path by replacing "*firefox" with "*firefox /path/to/firefox-bin".

Comment: Note that the -forcedBrowserModeRestOfLine option can be used to set the path to the FireFox executable.

Answer (score 0):

In my ubuntu 9.04 setup, I added the '/usr/lib/firefox-3.0.11' to my $PATH